# Serial communication between Arduino and computer cuts out after a while and doesn't reconnect. Why?

Tags: serial, communication, debugging, datalogger

I've just kept an experiment running the whole weekend. Arduino controlling heat and humidity and sending data over serial to my computer. I had a python program reading Serial data and populating an Excel spreadsheet every 10 seconds.

I walk in today delighted to see it didn't burn down the lab (there was a safety implemented, don't worry), but I saw that the excel sheet just stopped at some point. Row 9003.

Serial communication kept going, it seemed. After I stopped the script running in the console (Ctrl+C) and tried to restart the script, it told me it couldn't connect to the Arduino's COM port. Guess the serial communication didn't keep going, after all.

[image]

I open Arduino IDE. It sees the Arduino, tries to connect to it, but can't.

[image]

I open device manager and see the Arduino is recognized on COM4, as it should be.

[image]

Reset Arduino with button. No change. I repeat, *hard reset doesn't fix the issue*.

Turn power off and on again. Problem solved.

What happened and how do I fix this? Watchdog timer can perform a reset of the Arduino, but a reset doesn't fix this problem, clearly, only cutting the power.

I need help. Any advice is very much appreciated. A big thank you in advance to any kind souls.

Here's link to the GitHub code:WackoKacko/Data_Logging_Arduino_PC: CO2, RH, and TEMP monitoring (github.com)

To be clear, the Arduino isn't being powered by the laptop, it has its own power supply. USB cable to computer has VCC line severed, so only TX, RX, GND. Laptop is charging the whole time and is set to never fall asleep, perform updates, etc.

Finally, to rule out one more thing, at the beginning of the project, a solenoid valve I was switching would frequently reset the Arduino as if by magic. This forum led me to put an RC snubber across the solenoid's leads, and that fixed the problem. I don't believe my issue as it stands has anything to do with the circuit.

Comment: From what you tell, the Nano would be the one in the spotlight here. It might taken some beating by that solenoid, not that it matters. Try another Arduino is my advice.

Comment: I remember a case where a JSON encoder died on memory fragmentation. The symptoms were similar.

Comment: you could use an MCU with USB, like the ESP32S2, which makes windows go "beepity boop" when you software reset.

Comment: could you upload a circuit diagram?